# Spurs at 40 kHz frequency multiples

Tags: pll, vco

I have designed a PLL using an [ADF4106](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf) and a [VCO](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/94/CVCO33CL_0110_0150-2303240.pdf). I have taken references from [CN0290](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0290.pdf).
I have designed the loop filter using the ADSimmPll tool from Analog Devices.

[image]

I got below values from ADSimmPll

C1->143 nF

R1->230 R

C2->1.94 uF

R2->470 R

C3->64.9 nF

Below are the values that I have used

C1->0.1 uF

R1->220 R

C2->2.2 uF

R2->480 R

C3->0.1 uF

Loop filter bandwidth is 1.80 kHz and PD frequency is 40 kHz.

I am getting the spurs at multiples 40 kHz.

[image]

What can I do to suppress these spurs?

Comment: You mean 40k not 40M. What is your acceptance criteria and filter attenuation?

Comment: At first look, seems that spurs are at a level specified at figure 12 of datasheet.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes its 40KHz

Comment: Your spurs are about 65 dB lower (1,800 times lower in real numbers) than your main signal so, what's the problem in not suppressing them?

Comment: @Andyaka I will be using 12.88MHz generated here as reference clock frequency to other systems. I just want to make sure that these spurs does not cause any trouble

Comment: So, what's the problem in not suppressing those spurs? They are absolutely miniscule compared to the main signal at 12.88 MHz. Have you tried looking at the oscilloscope waveform?

Comment: Engineering top tip: kHz = kilohertz. KHz = kelvinhertz.

Comment: @user_1818839 122.88 MHz

Comment: @MightyBeard007 then my comment is probably irrelevant, I don't know your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think but, maybe you need to explain why you think the amplitude of those spurs might cause problems: -

[image]

Comment: @andyka I was expecting clean noise floor that's it. I am quite satisficed with the output. I just wanted to know if there was anything I can do to suppress those spurs.

Comment: There's barely anything to suppress and, given that the highest magnitude spur is extremely close to the required signal frequency, there is nothing practical or feasible that you can or ought to do @MightyBeard007

Comment: @Andyka I have another question. Why the spurs are at multiples of 40kHz ? Is it because the PFD is 40KHz?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 yes it is. Have we done here now? I've used the [ADF4111](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4110_4111_4112_4113.pdf) (very similar device) with a REF_frequency of 10 MHz (and no pre-scaling on the REF frequency) and I could see spurs on my 400 MHz output at every 10 MHz from 400 MHz.